# Given $f\in A(\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<2\})$ and $f(1)=0,f'(1)\neq0$ calculate the angle

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f\in A(\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<2\})$ and $f(1)=0,f'(1)\neq0$ setting $u=Re(f),v=Im(f)$ and assuming in a neighborhood oh1 the $u(z)=0$ define a smooth path $\gamma_0$ and the same for $v$ define $\gamma_1$.
Find the angle between $\gamma_0,\gamma_1$ at the point 1

Comment: $f'(1) \ne 0$ means $f$ conformal at $1$ hence it preserves angles, hence the answer is....

Comment: I assume the answer is $\pi/2$ but I don't see  how you got to it from the given information if you can do a formal answer please?

Comment: added one as required - in short $f$ sends those curves into the two coordinate axes near $0$ and since the latter have angle $90$ the original curves must have angle $90$ too; the formal proof is easy using the local inverse, but it can be done directly as above, just being careful with notations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f'(1) \ne 0$ means $f'(z) \ne 0$ in a small neighbourhood $U$ of $1$ so there is $g$ (holomorphic and conformal,so $g'(w) \ne 0$) defined on a small neighborhood $W$ of $0$ with $f \circ g(w)=w, w \in W$ and $g \circ f(z)=z, z \in U$.

If $w_1=x, w_0=y$ are the curves given by the real/imaginary axis in $W$, $\Im f\circ g(w_1)= \Im x=0$ amd $\Re f\circ g(w_0)=0$ so $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ are the images of $w_0, w_1$ under the conformal map $g$, so the angle is $90^{\circ}$ as expected